# What is the impact of not overwriting CMakeLists when importing code in Clion?

Tags: cmake, clion

We have a large project already using CMake. 
When importing it in CLion, it asks whether to overwrite the CMakeLists.txt. We don't want to annoy people who don't use the same IDE, thus we select "Open project". 
Has it any impact on the features available in Clion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has no impact.

Actually, if you were to "import" your project in CLion, the overwritten `CMakeLists.txt` would be almost useless, since it would contain just a list of all source files and one executable, as you could easily verify yourself.

"Import" is a CLion feature just to get started when a project is not under cmake already; if on the other hand a `CMakeLists.txt` is already there, just "Open" the project.